# Copy certain files from one folder to another using python

Tags: python, file, csv, filenames

I am trying to copy only certain files from one folder to another. The filenames are in a attribute table of a shapefile.

I am successful upto writing the filenames into a .csv file and list the column containing the list of the filenames to be transferred. I am stuck after that on how to read those filenames to copy them to another folder. I have read about using Shutil.copy/move but not sure how to use it. Any help is appreciated. Below is my script:

---

```
import arcpy
import csv
import os
import sys
import os.path
import shutil
from collections import defaultdict
fc = 'C:\\work_Data\\Export_Output.shp'
CSVFile = 'C:\\wokk_Data\\Export_Output.csv'
src = 'C:\\UC_Training_Areas'
dst = 'C:\\MOSAIC_Files'

fields = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(fc)]
if f.type <> 'Geometry':
    for i,f in enumerate(fields):

        if f in (['FID', "Area", 'Category', 'SHAPE_Area']):
            fields.remove (f)    

with open(CSVFile, 'w') as f:
f.write(','.join(fields)+'\n') 
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        f.write(','.join([str(r) for r in row])+'\n')

f.close()


columns = defaultdict(list) 
with open(CSVFile) as f:
  reader = csv.DictReader(f) 
  for row in reader: 
      for (k,v) in row.items(): 
         columns[k].append(v) 


print(columns['label'])
```

Comment: You may want to edit your code so that it is runnable via copy/paste.  The indentation, etc... is off right now.  Additionally, when you use the `with(open(filename, 'w') as f:....` idiom, you do not need to use a `f.close()`. When you exit the `with` block the file will be closed automatically..  Finally, a question ... in this example is the text printed in the final line `print(columns['label'])` the name of the file that you want to copy to your destination directory ?
Otherwise, I'm curious

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the name of the file
`columns['label']` you can use the following to move a file

```
srcpath = os.path.join(src, columns['label'])
dstpath = os.path.join(dst, columns['label'])
shutil.copyfile(srcpath, dstpath)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the script I used to solve my problem:

```
import os
import arcpy
import os.path
import shutil
featureclass = "C:\\work_Data\\Export_Output.shp"
src = "C:\\Data\\UC_Training_Areas"
dst = "C:\\Data\\Script"

rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(featureclass)
row = rows.next()
while row:
     print row.Label
     shutil.move(os.path.join(src,str(row.Label)),dst)
     row = rows.next()
```

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this ways way source and destination
assuming you want to copy file from your picture folder to your image folder located somewhere in your machine destination
X is your machine name
Z is the file name``

```
import os;
import shutil;
import glob;

source="C:/Users/X/Pictures/test/Z.jpg"
dest="C:/Users/Public/Image"

    if os.path.exists(dest):
    print("this folder exit in this dir")
else:
    dir = os.mkdir(dest)

for file in glob._iglob(os.path.join(source),""):
    shutil.copy(file,dest)
    print("done")
```