# Copy files from multiple specific subfolders

Tags: python, operating-system, glob, shutil

Under the file path D:/src, I have images folders and its subfolders which have a regular structure as follows:

```
Folder A
- Subfolder a
- Subfolder b
- Subfolder c
Folder B
- Subfolder a
- Subfolder b
- Subfolder c
- Subfolder d
Folder C
- Subfolder a
- Subfolder b
- Subfolder c
...
```

I want to copy all .jpg files in Subfolder b from Folder A, B, C and so on to a new folder Subfolder b in D:/dst. How can I do it in Python? Thanks.

```
Subfolder b
-xxx.jpg
-xyx.jpg
-yxz.jpg
...
```

Here is what I have found from the following link may helps:

[Copy certain files from one folder to another using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29885640/copy-certain-files-from-one-folder-to-another-using-python)

```
import os;
import shutil;
import glob;

source="C:/Users/X/Pictures/test/Z.jpg"
dest="C:/Users/Public/Image"

    if os.path.exists(dest):
    print("this folder exit in this dir")
else:
    dir = os.mkdir(dest)

for file in glob._iglob(os.path.join(source),""):
    shutil.copy(file,dest)
    print("done")
```

Comment: Where do you want to copy it to ?

Comment: To a new folder under D:/dest/Subfolder b. I updated question. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for all kind helps. I'll try those methods and let you know the results. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
import os
from os.path import join, isfile

BASE_PATH = 'd:/test'
SUBFOLDER = 'Subfolder b'

for folder, subfolders, *_ in os.walk(BASE_PATH):
    if SUBFOLDER in subfolders:
        full_path = join(BASE_PATH, folder, SUBFOLDER)
        files = [f for f in os.listdir(full_path) if isfile(join(full_path, f)) and f.lower().endswith(('.jpg', '.jpeg'))]
        for f in files:
            file_path = join(full_path, f)
            print (f'Copy {f} somewehere')
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have 2 levels of nesting

```
root_dir = './data'
dest_dir = './new_location'
os.listdir(root_dir)

for folder in os.listdir(root_dir):
    folder_path = os.path.join(root_dir, folder)
    if os.path.isdir(folder_path):
        for subfolder in os.listdir(folder_path):
            if subfolder == 'Subfolder B':
                subfolder_path = os.path.join(root_dir, folder, subfolder)
                print(subfolder_path)
                for filename in os.listdir(subfolder_path):
                    file_path = os.path.join(root_dir, folder, subfolder, filename)
                    dest_path = os.path.join(dest_dir, filename)
                    shutil.copy(file_path, dest_path)
                    print("Copied ", file_path, "to", dest_path)
```

You just need 2 for loops, and in the the inner for loop you just check whether the folder name matches `Subfolder B`. If it does then copy all the files inside that directory to your destination folder.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a short script that should do the work...

```
import os

# list all the directories in current directory
dirs = [x[0] for x in os.walk("D:/src")]

for d in dirs:
    ## list all files in A/b/*, B/b/*, C/b/*...
    files_to_copy = os.listdir(os.path.join(d, "b"))  
    for f in files_to_copy:
        if f.endswith(".jpg"):  ## copy the relevant files to dest
            shutil.copy(os.path.join(d, "b", f), os.path.join(dest, f))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import shutil
import os
 
 
def move_files(source_director, destination_director):
    # select the files in the source directory
    fisiere = [fisier for fisier in os.listdir(source_director) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(source_director, fisier))]
    print(fisiere)
    # each file in the source directory is moved to the destination directory
    for fisier in fisiere:
        shutil.move(source_director + '\\' + fisier, destination_director)
 
def copy_files(source_director, destination_director):
    # select the files in the source directory
    fisiere = [fisier for fisier in os.listdir(source_director) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(source_director, fisier))]
    print(fisiere)
    # each file in the source directory is copied to the destination directory
    for fisier in fisiere:
        shutil.copy(source_director + '\\' + fisier, destination_director)
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
     # WARNING: paths to directories must be written with '\\' (double backslash)
     # here you set the DIN directory you want to move / copy the files

    source_director = 'c:\\Folder'
 
    destination_director = 'c:\\Folder\\Subfolder1\\Subfolder2'
 
    #CASE 1
    # move_files(source_director, destination_director)
 
    #CASE 2
    copy_files(source_director, destination_director)
```

THE SOURCE OF THIS CODE HERE:

https://neculaifantanaru.com/en/python-copy-or-moves-files-from-a-folder-to-another-folder.html