# How to move files from multiple specific subfolders in the same directory?

Tags: python, file, file-move

I'm trying to do the same as in this question:
[Copy files from multiple specific subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54185490/copy-files-from-multiple-specific-subfolders).

But none of the answers work for me at all. When I execute the py in my Windows cmd it doesn't even go into the loops, as I receive no `print()` line in the cmd window after executing.

I've tried [this solution](https://neculaifantanaru.com/en/python-copy-or-moves-files-from-a-folder-to-another-folder.html) which copies the files from the directory but ignores all subfolders in that directory entirely.

I have tried looking into `shutil` but I don't think I can use it for my case because of the subfolders? It's really important that I don't keep the subfolder structure but just move all the files into one directory.

This is what I have right now but the output unfortunately keeps the folder structure:

```
import shutil
import os

# Define the source and destination path
source = "d:\\test"
destination = "d:\\test\SubfolderB"

# code to move the files from sub-folder to main folder.
files = os.listdir(source)
for file in files:
    file_name = os.path.join(source, file)
    shutil.move(file_name, destination)
print("Files Moved")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issues 1 and 2**:
It appears that two of the primary issues in the original code is that `os.listdir` does not recurse into each sub-directory, but only provides a list of file and directory *names*, rather than the full path. So a two-fold issue here.

To address this, the built-in `glob` library can be used. Per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob), a glob pattern of `'**'` along with the parameter `recursive=True`, will dive into each sub-directory and return the *full file path*, as desired.

Note: If only a specific file type is required, the pattern can be changed to `**/*.txt`, or whatever file extension you're after.

**Issue 3:**
Additionally, the `shutil.move` command needs the full path to the destination, *including* the filename; which the original code does not address.

#### Example code:

```
import os
import shutil
from glob import glob

# Path setup.
path = './filemove'
dest = './filemove_dest'

# Collect files.
files = glob(os.path.join(path, '**'), recursive=True)

# Ensure destination path exists.
if not os.path.isdir(dest):
    os.makedirs(dest)
# Move all files.
for f in files:
    if os.path.isfile(f):
        base = os.path.basename(f)
        shutil.move(f, os.path.join(dest, base))
```

#### Original file structure:

```
./dir1
./dir1/dir1_file1
./dir1/dir1_file2
./dir1/dir1_file3
./dir1/dir1_file4
./dir1/dir1_file5
...
./dir5
./dir5/dir5_file1
./dir5/dir5_file2
./dir5/dir5_file3
./dir5/dir5_file4
./dir5/dir5_file5
```

#### Results:

```
./filemove_dest/dir1_file1
./filemove_dest/dir1_file2
./filemove_dest/dir1_file3
...
./filemove_dest/dir5_file3
./filemove_dest/dir5_file4
./filemove_dest/dir5_file5
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation!! The recursive loop is so easy to add, i was really confused by it at first, but i understand it much better now.

Comment: Ah excellent. Glad to hear the explanation has helped you. My pleasure.